# Winforms label indents the text when changing it

Tags: winforms, label, indentation

When I Change the text of a winforms label from outside the InitializedComponent method, it is automatically indented on the first line of each paragraph.

¿Any ideas why this is happening?

Thank you.

Comment: Check the Margin and Padding of the label.

Comment: It only indentes the first line of each paragraph, and only after change the text (not with the initial text). It seems it is not related with margin / padding because only onle line per paragraph is affected

Comment: Can you post your code?